# GROUP BY PRIORITIZE NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE :

```
 ID                    in                   out
  1   2000-01-01 00:00:00   2000-01-01 12:00:00
  1   2000-01-02 00:00:00                  NULL
  2   2000-01-01 00:00:00   2000-01-01 12:00:00 
  2   2000-01-02 00:00:00   2000-01-02 11:00:00
  3   2000-01-01 00:00:00                  NULL
```

RESULT :

```
 ID                    in                   out
  1   2000-01-02 00:00:00                  NULL
  2   2000-01-02 00:00:00   2000-01-01 11:00:00
  3   2000-01-01 00:00:00                  NULL
```

So I want to get the most recent *in's* in all *ID's* and also order them according to ID.
I tried GROUP BY but that seems to get the one with value.

What I have at the moment is similar to

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ID 
ORDER BY OUT IS NULL DESC, OUT DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the appropriate value as well as doing the order by:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.id, max(t.in) as maxin
      from t
      group by t.id
     ) tsum
     on t.id = tsum.id and t.in = tsum.maxin
order by id
```

Comment: Hi, is there another way not use a subquery? From my experience subqueries execution is slow.

Comment: @RjPo . . . In MySQL, I don't believe so.  If you have an index on `id, in`, the subquery should be pretty fast.